# Find String Length without recursion in C

Tags: c, string, string-length

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
    int str1[25];
    int i=0;
    printf("Enter a string\n");
    gets(str1);
    while(str1[i]!='\0')
    {
        i++;
    }
    printf("String Length %d",i);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

i'm always getting string length as 33. what is wrong with my code.

Comment: `main()` returns `int`, you're strange to have `return 0;` but declare it as `void`.

Comment: There is no recursion here, only iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because, you have declared your array as type `int`

```
int str1[25]; 

^^^-----------Change it to `char`
```

Comment: @AjmalRasi: and always remember the prototype of main 
int main( void )
or
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )

Answer (score 1):

You don't show an example of your input, but in general I would guess that you're suffering from buffer overflow due to the dangers of `gets()`. That function is deprecated, meaning it should *never* be used in newly-written code.

Use `fgets()` instead:

```
if(fgets(str1, sizeof str1, stdin) != NULL)
{
  /* your code here */
}
```

Also, of course your entire loop is just `strlen()` but you knew that, right?

**EDIT**: Gaah, completely missed the mis-declaration, of course your string should be `char str1[25];` and not `int`.

Answer (score 1):

So, a lot of answers have already told you to use `char str1[25];` instead of `int str1[25]` but nobody explained why. So here goes:

A `char` has length of one byte (by definition in C standard). But an `int` uses more bytes (how much depends on architecture and compiler; let's assume 4 here). So if you access index 2 of a `char` array, you get 1 byte at memory offset 2, but if you access index 2 of an `int` array, you get 4 bytes at memory offset 8.

When you call `gets` (which should be avoided since it's unbounded and thus might overflow your array), a string gets copied to the address of `str1`. That string really is an array of `char`. So imaging the string would be `123` plus terminating null character. The memory would look like:

```
Adress:    0    1    2    3
Content:  0x31 0x32 0x33 0x00
```

When you read `str1[0]` you get 4 bytes at once, so `str1[0]` does not return 0x31, you'll get either 0x00333231 (little-endian) or 0x31323300 (big endian).

Accessing `str1[1]` is already beyond the string.

Now, why do you get a string length of 33? That's actually random and you're "lucky" that the program didn't crash instead. From the start address of `str1`, you fetch `int` values until you finally get four 0 bytes in a row. In your memory, there's some random garbage and by pure luck you encounter four 0 bytes after having read 33*4=132 bytes.

So here you can already see that *bounds checks* are very important: your array is supposed to contain 25 characters. But `gets` may already write beyond that (solution: use `fgets` instead). Then you scan without bounds and may thus also access memory well beyond you array and may finally run into non-existing memory regions (which would crash your program). Solution for that: do bounds checks, for example:

```
// "sizeof(str1)" only works correctly on real arrays here,
// not on "char *" or something!
int l;
for (l = 0; l < sizeof(str1); ++l) {
    if (str1[l] == '\0') {
      // End of string
      break;
    }
}

if (l == sizeof(str1)) {
  // Did not find a null byte in array!
} else {
   // l contains valid string length.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest certain changes to your code.

1) conio.h

```
    This is not a header that is in use. So avoid using it.
```

2) gets

```
    gets is also not recommended by anyone. So avoid using it. Use fgets() instead
```

3) int str1[25]
 If you want to store a string it should be

```
     char str1[25]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the string declaration `int str1[25]`. It must be `char` and not `int`

```
char str1[25]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void main() //"void" should be "int"
{
    int str1[25]; //"int" should be "char"
    int i=0;
    printf("Enter a string\n");
    gets(str1);
    while(str1[i]!='\0')
    {
        i++;
    }
    printf("String Length %d",i);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```